# jQuery animation always same speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I want to change the speed of my jQuery animation so that it is always the same speed. I have 4 divs that animate the background image's position on `mouseenter`. I now see that the animation always has different speed, it always takes 2500 milliseconds. I want the speed to always be the same, how is this possible?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="imgholder">
<div class="imggridcol" id="linksboven"></div>
<div class="imggridcol" id="rechtsboven"></div>
<div class="imggridcol" id="linksonder"></div>
<div class="imggridcol" id="rechtsonder"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#imgholder {
width:960px;
height:380px;
overflow:hidden;
background: url("http://crispme.com/wp-content/uploads/4379.jpg?pass") no-repeat;
background-position:50% 50%;
background-size:150% 150%;
}

.imggridcol {
width:50%;
height:50%;
margin:0px;
float:left;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#linksboven").mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).parent().stop().animate({
  backgroundPositionX: '0%',
  backgroundPositionY: '0%'
  }, 2500, "linear");
});

$("#rechtsboven").mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).parent().stop().animate({
  backgroundPositionX: '100%',
  backgroundPositionY: '0%'
  }, 2500, "linear");
});

$("#linksonder").mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).parent().stop().animate({
  backgroundPositionX: '0%',
  backgroundPositionY: '100%'
  }, 2500, "linear");
});


$("#rechtsonder").mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).parent().stop().animate({
  backgroundPositionX: '100%',
  backgroundPositionY: '100%'
  }, 2500, "linear");
});

$(".imggridcol").mouseleave(function() {
 $(this).parent().stop();   
});
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PqPvz/)

Comment: I think the reason the speed is different is because you're setting how long it takes the animation to go from it's current position to the end frame. If you're halfway there already the speed will be twice as fast because there's half as far to go there's a link here that might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331234/how-to-make-constant-animation-using-jquery

Comment: That's because `animate` does whatever in the time you give. In your case, you are moving the background to one side or another in 2.5 seconds. For example, if you start the animation from the left of the image, it will last 2.5 secs to move the entire image to the right. If you start the animation from the center (the image is centered) it will last the same time to advance the half of the pixels, so the effect will be that it is slower.

Answer (score 0):

http://lukeshumard.github.io/supremation/

following on from my comment, this actually appears to be the answer. This jQuery plugin should help. Just call, for example:

```
$("#linksboven").mouseenter(function() {
      $(this).parent().stop().supremate({
      backgroundPositionX: '0%',
      backgroundPositionY: '0%'
      }, 2500, "linear");
});
```

instead of the animate function and it'll handle the rest

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PqPvz/2/ this doesn't seem to work (might be because I'm using background-position?)